# Are questions about removing DRM on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Can I ask questions about removing Digital Rights Management (DRM)?  I'm aware the legality of this may be debatable.

Context: I've bought a paper book, but after more than 3 weeks I'm still waiting.  I need the book in preparation for a deadline that is coming up soon, so I intend to buy the ebook.  Sources for the ebook that I can find are in EPUB format with DRM from Adobe Digital Editions, which apparently does not work (well) on my Linux computer, which means I cannot (properly) read the ebook unless I remove DRM first.  There may be ways to do that, but would asking so be on-topic on this site?  I have read removing DRM may be illegal in some places, which might make it off-topic, but in my humble opinion my intended use case is entirely ethical.

Comment: Under the circumstances, I have no issue with this, but I've marked this as featured in hopes to bring attention to the question. We can let the rest of the community weigh in.

Comment: The servers of this site might be located in places where this is a crime (i.e. USA).